# Custom button to open opportunity after lead is converted

Tags: apex, javascript, opportunity, button, convert

I have a global class that creates an Opp from a custom lead conversion button. 
The problem is that the button works to convert the lead to an Opp but it does not open the Opp. I get an error message that "that URL does not exist".

Ideas?

```
global class convertLead{
    WebService static Id  convertLeadtoAcc(string id){
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel 
                                    FROM LeadStatus 
                                    WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];                
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        Id OpportunityId=[select ConvertedOpportunityId from Lead where id=:id].ConvertedOpportunityId;
        return OpportunityId;
    }
}
```

My button is an OnClick Javascript button with this code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
var opportunityId=sforce.apex.execute("ConvertLeadCustom","convertLeadtoAcc", {id:"{!Lead.Id}"});
var newURL = "/"+opportunityId[0].id+"/e";
window.location.href=newURL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your method returning opportunity Id means var opportunityId contains the actual opportunity Id

You just need redirect to

```
var newURL = "/"+opportunityId+"/e";
window.location.href=newURL;
```

Comment: @MelissaLenai Seeing as Ratan's answer solved your problem please mark it as the correct solution.